# Making 2013 Pro SSD work on another Mac - Computer closes after entering the password

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, filevault

My 2013 Pro Mac is broken and I extracted its SSD and mount on an another Mac. The opening screen opens and I see the background image that I have used before and correct username on the screen. However, when i try to enter by supplying the password the computer closes down. What might be the problem?

Note : The computer used for recovering SSD is 2013 model mac pro, the same with the one the ssd belongs to.

UPDATE :

I can't reach the details here as I am not trying directly but contacting the dealer. What I can say is that

(1) I don't remember having filevault enabled,

(2) the opening screen where you choose between different users or 'guest' user opens without a problem,

(3) the computer directly powers off without prompting any errors when tried to enter through main user (my user),

(4) guest user opens and run without a problem.

(5) When tried to reach the same SSD through windows using disk recovery programs, they recognize the SSD as passive state and no further process can be performed,

(6) it is not recognizable by prograrms such as TransMac.

Comment: "Opening screen" doesn't specifically describe anything nor does "Closes down" (powes off? Crashes? Rejects the login?); please describe *exactly* what you see during the boot process. It's important. If this is the disk encryption prompt, that's different from the user login prompt.

Were they both running the same version of MacOS? One possible explanation is that the machine you transplanted into isn't running a new enough BootROM, but there isn't really enough info here to troubleshoot with.

Can you boot into recovery mode? (apple-R immediately after power-on)

Comment: It's the normal openings screen where you normally choose between users. Powers off means that it actually shuts down without prompting anything. The SSD actually injected into the main SSD place of the Mac so it runs the same OS (I don't know how this mechanism works, If OSs are installed a different place other than SSD it might have been running a different OS) How to check the BOOTRoom? Ill check to boot innto recovery mode.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you're incoherent - and not answering my questions (namely, "please describe exactly what you see during the boot process. It's important.") If English is not your primary language, you may be able to get support on one of the non-English StackExchange sites mentioned here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange

Comment: Details really are important here. Can you add a picture (use a smartphone if necessary) of the screen you enter username/password? Did you have FileVault enabled on the disk? Can you boot into Recovery Mode and analyze the system from there? Also, please have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3387/ask-different-question-checklist for further ideas on how to improve the question.

Comment: In addition to that: Please don't delete questions and repost them, you will loose all clarifying comments that way. It's better to edit questions into shape if necessary.

Comment: I updated and added notes to my question.